# How to filter SIP character correctly in Django with MariaDB?

Tags: python, mysql, django, unicode, mariadb

I was trying to filter out some data from my database, but it failed filtering and eventually collected all rows from the table when filtering SIP (Supplementary Ideographic Plane) characters such as "" in ext-B, "" in ext-F.

This only applies in production environment using MariaDB (10.1.41-MariaDB-0+deb9u1 Debian 9.9), but it is totally normal in development environment (SQLite 3).

mysite/settings/production.py

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        ...
        'OPTIONS': {
            'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'; SET NAMES utf8mb4;",
            'charset': 'utf8mb4',
            'use_unicode': True,
        }
    }
}
```

mysite/myapp/views.py

```py
def query_dzih(dzih):
    result = list(Dzih.objects.filter(dzih=dzih))
```

Query Explain (MariaDB)

```py
>>> Dzih.objects.filter(dzih="\U000200CB")
<QuerySet [<Dzih: Dzih object (0)>, <Dzih: Dzih object (10)>, <Dzih: Dzih
object (11)>, <Dzih: Dzih object (13)>, <Dzih: Dzih object (399)>, <Dzih: Dzih object (456)>, <Dzih: Dzih object (740)>, <Dzih: Dzih object (782)>, <Dzih: Dzih object (922)>, <Dzih: Dzih object (1006)>, <Dzih: Dzih object (1010)>, <Dzih: Dzih object (1020)>, <Dzih: Dzih object (1021)>, <Dzih: Dzih object (1212)>, <Dzih: Dzih object (1316)>, <Dzih: Dzih object (1528)>, <Dzih: Dzih object (1684)>, <Dzih: Dzih object (1720)>, <Dzih: Dzih object (1731)>, <Dzih: Dzih object (1734)>, '...(remaining elements truncated)...']>
>>> Dzih.objects.filter(dzih="\U000200CB").explain()
'1 SIMPLE myapp_dzih ref myapp_dzih_dzih_9a6b0a3f myapp_dzih_dzih_9a6b0a3f 766 const 59 Using where'
```

Query Explain (SQLite)

```py
>>> Dzih.objects.filter(dzih="\U000200CB")
<QuerySet [<Dzih: Dzih object (3707)>]>

>>> Dzih.objects.filter(dzih="\U000200CB").explain()
'3 0 0 SEARCH TABLE myapp_dzih USING INDEX myapp_dzih_dzih_9a6b0a3f (dzih=?)'
```

MariaDB

```sql
MariaDB [django]> show variables like "chara%";
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+

MariaDB [django]> SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM myapp_dzih;
+----------+--------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+---------------------------------+---------+
| Field    | Type         | Collation          | Null | Key | Default | Extra | Privileges                      | Comment |
+----------+--------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+---------------------------------+---------+
| dzihn    | int(11)      | NULL               | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       | select,insert,update,references |         |
| dzih     | varchar(255) | utf8mb4_general_ci | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       | select,insert,update,references |         |
| dzihm    | varchar(255) | utf8mb4_general_ci | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       | select,insert,update,references |         |
| dziho    | varchar(100) | utf8mb4_general_ci | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       | select,insert,update,references |         |
| dzihe    | varchar(255) | utf8mb4_general_ci | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       | select,insert,update,references |         |
+----------+--------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+---------------------------------+---------+
```

SHOW CREATE TABLE (MariaDB)

```sql
CREATE TABLE `myapp_dzih` (
  `dzihn` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dzih` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `dzihm` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `dziho` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `dzihe` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`dzihn`),
  KEY `myapp_dzih_dzih_9a6b0a3f` (`dzih`(191)),
  KEY `myapp_dzih_dzihm_e1ed3e47` (`dzihm`(191)),
  KEY `myapp_dzih_dziho_1e5984df` (`dziho`),
  KEY `myapp_dzih_dzihe_0e01a5cd` (`dzihe`(191))
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

```sql
MariaDB [django]> SELECT dzih, HEX(dzih) FROM myapp_dzih WHERE dzih=UNHEX('f0a0838b');
+------+-----------+
| dzih | HEX(dzih) |
+------+-----------+
|    | F0A093A5  |
|    | F0A6B38A  |
|    | F0A59DA9  |
|    | F0A995BE  |
|    | F0A786A8  |
|    | F0A190A8  |
|    | F0A9B1A1  |
|    | F0A4BABA  |
|    | F0A49494  |
|    | F0A2B588  |
|    | F0A0A8A7  |
|    | F0A986B5  |
|    | F0A986B5  |
|    | F0A68D92  |
|    | F0A0AF91  |
|    | F0A4A394  |
|    | F0A58191  |
|    | F0A58195  |
|    | F0A28489  |
|    | F0A1B182  |
|    | F0A69088  |
|    | F0A18FB3  |
|    | F0A58ABD  |
|    | F0A0AC9B  |
|    | F0A98E9F  |
|    | F0A082A4  |
|    | F0A59D8C  |
|    | F0A488A6  |
|    | F0A68AAE  |
|    | F0A0AA9A  |
|    | F0A3A5BA  |
|    | F0A2939C  |
|    | F0A7AA9C  |
|    | F0A7AEAB  |
|    | F0A1ADB4  |
|    | F0A5BCB6  |
|    | F0A5A5BB  |
|    | F0A188BC  |
|    | F0A9B0B2  |
|    | F0A892AA  |
|    | F0A0838B  |
|    | F0A0A8AE  |
|    | F0A38594  |
|    | F0A3859B  |
|    | F0A0A0A6  |
|    | F0A0AC9D  |
|    | F0A2A692  |
|    | F0A2A68F  |
|    | F0A7B39F  |
|    | F0A6A39E  |
|    | F0A8BDBF  |
|    | F0A7B38F  |
|    | F0A18DAC  |
|    | F0A7B6A0  |
|    | F0A083AC  |
|    | F0A28F9A  |
|    | F0A4BBB2  |
|    | F0A2809C  |
|    | F0A0AC9E  |
+------+-----------+

MariaDB [django]> SELECT * FROM myapp_dzih WHERE HEX(dzih)='f0a0838b';
+------+
| dzih |
+------+
|    |
+------+
```

Comment: Please provide `SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM ... WHERE ...` so we can see what is being stored.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: @RickJames Thank you. I've added them just now. It yielded really strange result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First to address the "strange results".

```
select '' = '' collate utf8mb4_general_ci;      -- yields 1
select '' = '' collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci;      -- yields 1
select '' = '' collate utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;  -- yields 0
```

That is, the collation matters.  There are a number of places where the COLLATION may be coming from, depending on the specifics of the query.  (Notice how I managed to bypass the settings to make this test.)

```
utf8mb4_general_ci -- simple-minded
utf8mb4_unicode_ci -- from the old Unicode 4.0 standard
utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci -- Unicode 5.20, apparently handling Chinese differently
future:  Unicode 9.0 is available in MySQL 8.0
```

Your tests:

```
dzih=UNHEX('f0a0838b')  -- test as strings, based, I think, on the collation of dzih
HEX(dzih)='f0a0838b'  -- test the 8-char hex strings
```

Here are some workarounds for the 191 kludge:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits#767_limit_in_innodb_indexes